# Formulários CF7 - desabilitação do botão Submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Olá,

No meu formulário CF7 tenho o seguinte código para habilitar o botão Submit (Id=enviar):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('enviar').disabled=false;
  }
  </script>

   .
   .
   .

   <strong>Confirmo que li e  aceito as condições de participação [acceptance aceito id:aceito]</strong></p>      
   <p></p>
   [submit id:enviar "enviar"]
```

O campo de aceitação (Id=aceito) está ligado por defeito mas ao clickar no botão Submit é apresentada a seguinte mensagem:

"Tem que aceitar os termos e condições antes de enviar a sua mensagem."

E se desligar o campo de aceitação, o botão submit fica automaticamente desabilitado. Alguém sabe porque é que isto acontece?
Procuro ajuda...

Comment: Marcelo como proceder quando tenho novos dados para publicar? Informaram-me que deveria colocar nova pergunta. Se estou errada agradecia que me informasse como proceder...

Comment: Todas suas perguntas foram relacionadas a um mesmo problema, seria interessante acrescentar informações editando ela, não publicando uma nova pergunta